# Multistep form with two terms checkboxes on different steps failed to validate properly using jQuery validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Form which has two checkboxes for agreement on different steps (first and last). First one is working totally fine, however the last step is not working properly.

Here is html code

```
<form method="post" id="prizeRegistration" action="submit_book.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset id="step1" class="publisher">
                    <div class="stepSec01">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Are you a Publisher?<span class="strik">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="check">
                                        <ul class="radioCls">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="radio" id="Yes" checked="" name="publisher" value="yes">
                                                <label for="Yes"> <span></span>Yes</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="radio" id="No" name="publisher" value="no">
                                                <label for="No"> <span></span>No</label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="error" id="error_publisher"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ....
                            ....
                            ....
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <p>By checking the box below, you hereby declare that all information submitted by you holds true.<span class="strik adStrik">*</span></p>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="agreement" value="agree" />
                                        <label for="agreement"> <span></span>I agree</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="error" id="error_agreement"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="stepone" class="btn next">Next</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="step2" class="book" style="display:none;">
                   ...
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="step3" class="author" style="display:none;">
                   ....
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="step4" class="editor" style="display:none;">
                    .....
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="step5" class="declaration" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="stepSec05">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <p>I hereby declare that all information submitted as part of the form is true to my knowledge. Any information shared with me (as a representative of my Publishing House)
                                            will be kept confidential. A breach in the same will lead to the disqualification of the entries made by the Publishing House, for the foreseeable future.<span class="strik">*</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="declaration" name="declaration" value="agree" />
                                        <label for="declaration"><span></span>I Agree</label>
                                        <div class="error" id="error_declaration"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" id="stepfive" class="btn">Submit</button> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Here is jQuery validation code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".error").removeClass("error");
        $(".next").click(function() {
            var form = $("#prizeRegistration");
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("agreement", function(value, element) {

                if ($("#agreement").is(":checked")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, "Please check the box.");
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("declaration", function(value, element) {
                //var ckb_status = $("#declaration_agreement").prop('checked');
                if ($("#declaration").is(":checked")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, "Please check the box.");
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
            }, "Letters only please");

            $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
                return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param * 1000000)
            }, 'File size must be less than {0} MB');

            form.validate({
                // ignore: [':not(checkbox:hidden)'],
                submitHandler: function() {
                    $('.loaderhome').show();
                    form.submit();
                },
                focusCleanup: true,
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    var name = $(element).attr("name");
                    error.insertAfter($("#error_" + name));
                },
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    },
                    publisher: {
                        required: true,

                    },
                    pbh_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    imprint_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    reg_address: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    reg_phone: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength: 10,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    contact_person: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    cp_email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    },
                    cp_phone: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength: 10,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    proof: {
                        required: true,
                        filesize: 2
                    },
                    agreement: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    published: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    english: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    book_title: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    published_date: {
                        required: true,

                    },
                    publishing_date: {
                        // required: true

                    },
                    isbn_code: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength: 13,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    orignal_title: {
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    original_lang: {
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    original_publisher: {
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    original_pub_date: {

                    },
                    original_isbn_code: {
                        number: true,
                        maxlength: 13,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    other_territory_pub: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    territory_of_pub: {
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    other_territory_date_of_pub: {

                    },
                    book_cover: {
                        required: true,
                        filesize: 2
                    },
                    ebook: {
                        required: true,
                        filesize: 2
                    },
                    author_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    author_date_of_birth: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    author_email: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    author_address: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    author_proof_of_citizen: {
                        required: true,
                        filesize: 2
                    },

                    editor_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true
                    },
                    editor_email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    },
                    editor_contact_number: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength: 10,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    declaration: {
                        required: true,
                    }

                },


            });
            console.log(form);
            if (form.valid() === true) {

                if ($('#step1').is(":visible")) {
                    current_fs = $('#step1');
                    next_fs = $('#step2');
                    $('#publisher').removeClass('active');
                    $('#publisher').addClass('grnactive');
                    $('#book').addClass('active');
                } else if ($('#step2').is(":visible")) {
                    current_fs = $('#step2');
                    next_fs = $('#step3');
                    $('#book').removeClass('active');
                    $('#book').addClass('grnactive');
                    $('#author').addClass('active');
                } else if ($('#step3').is(":visible")) {
                    current_fs = $('#step3');
                    next_fs = $('#step4');
                    $('#author').removeClass('active');
                    $('#author').addClass('grnactive');
                    $('#editor').addClass('active');
                } else if ($('#step4').is(":visible")) {
                    current_fs = $('#step4');
                    next_fs = $('#step5');
                    $('#editor').removeClass('active');
                    $('#editor').addClass('grnactive');
                    $('#declaration').addClass('active');
                } else if ($('#step5').is(":visible")) {
                    current_fs = $('#step5');
                    next_fs = $('#step1');
                    $('#declaration').addClass('active');
                    $('#declaration').addClass('grnactive');
                }


                next_fs.show();
                current_fs.hide();
            }
        });

        $('.backBtn').click(function() {
            if ($('#step5').is(":visible")) {
                current_fs = $('#step5');
                next_fs = $('#step4');
            } else if ($('#step4').is(":visible")) {
                current_fs = $('#step4');
                next_fs = $('#step3');
            } else if ($('#step3').is(":visible")) {
                current_fs = $('#step3');
                next_fs = $('#step2');
            } else if ($('#step2').is(":visible")) {
                current_fs = $('#step2');
                next_fs = $('#step1');
            }
            next_fs.show();
            current_fs.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried to change name, for, id. It adds valid class automatically when we come to last step declaration block. I want it to show error when submitted without it is checked. However, it work when you click or toggle checkbox only.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have another checkbox, which shows up only in the last step? What is the ID of that checkbox? Is it `declaration` (since I see that in your Javascript code)?

Comment: You are showing us WAY TOO MUCH code.  Take the time to strip it down to just enough code that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do not put `form.validate()` inside of the `(".next").click()` handler.  It makes no sense.  `validate()` is only how you first INITIALIZE the plugin... it does not need to be called every time you click on the next step.

Comment: @FiddlingAway yes it is